# invertible matrices are positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

A inverse matrix $B^{-1}$ is it automatically positive definite?

Invertible matrices have full rank, and so, nonzero eigenvalues, which in turn implies nonzero determinant (as the product of eigenvalues).

*Considering the comments below, the answer is no. But if $B$ is positive semi-definite, the existence of its inverse imply $B$ positive definite?

Comment: Consider $A=-I$

Comment: Is ${1 \over (-1)}$ positive? It is generally a good idea to check if a hypothesis works in the $1 \times 1$ case first.

Comment: Thanks. Can you take a look in the above update?

Comment: If $B$ is positive semi-definite, then its eigenvalues are non-negative; if $B$ is invertible, then its eigenvalues are non-zero; if both, then its eigenvalues are positive, and that means $B$ is positive definite

Comment: For clarification of the comment above: note that the statement that $B$ is positive definite implies that $B$ is symmetric. Eventually, we use the fact that a symmetric matrix with positive eigenvalues is positive definite.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so, symmetric and invertible matrices are positive definite.

Comment: @CelineHarumi:  no, $\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}$ is symmetric and invertible but not positive definite

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to original question:**

No; just because a matrix has an inverse does not mean it is positive definite.

For example, $\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}$ is its own inverse but is not positive definite.

**Answer to edited (additional) question:**

Yes; if a matrix is positive semi-definite and invertible, then it is positive definite.

This can be related to your correct assertion

that a matrix that is invertible has non-zero determinant so cannot have an eigenvalue of $0$.